# Charts iOS: How do I implement tap recognizing for LineChart label

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I have got a wide `LineChart` with many entries. I want to let user tap (or better longtap/3D touch) on an entry to show modal card where user could edit data entry. I tried implementing `chartValueSelected` but the problem is that it runs even when user taps to scroll (i e taps without releasing finger) which is not how a button should behave. Is there any way to implement tap recognizing for `LineChart` label?

Answer (score 2):

You can attach your own gesture recognizer to `LineChartView` and use method `getHighlightByTouchPoint` to get information about the selected point.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...
    let longTapRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onLongTap))
    lineChartView.addGestureRecognizer(longTapRecognizer)
    // ...
}

@objc func onLongTap(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        let highlight = lineChartView.getHighlightByTouchPoint(recognizer.location(in: lineChartView))
        print("\(highlight)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that overriding the tap gesture recognizer for the chart can work. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921792/how-to-detect-tap-gesture-on-chart-marker) has some answers based on someone who was looking for a similar solution.